# Why div is showing empty in this case

Tags: jquery

The specified div has got some content inside it , but it is still showing the div as empty

```
<div class="Itm_right_aside">
    <div style="display:none;" class="toppcrustdata">
      <div id="popupinner703" class="popup_inner addonsContent">

      </div>
   </div>
</div>

if ($('.Itm_right_aside .toppcrustdata').html()) {
    alert('empty');
} else {
    alert('Not empty');
}
```

I am checking if the class  toppcrustdata div has got any data under it , but inspite of some content it is still showing empty

Could you please let me know why

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/77/

Comment: Huh? Your alert shows because your if is true; your if is true because the html() function returns data.

Answer (score 4):

`html()` does not return a boolean value, it returns a string. Check against an empty string instead:

```
if ($('.Itm_right_aside .toppcrustdata').html() == '')
```

Alternatively, you can invert the logic of your own `if()` statement:

```
if( ! $('.Itm_right_aside .toppcrustdata').html() )
```

[**jsFiddel Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/78/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `!` condition in if statement. also i would suggest you to find the length of html returned in if statement:

```
if (!$('.Itm_right_aside .toppcrustdata').html().length) {
  alert('empty');
} else {
  alert('Not empty');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is wrong. It's basically saying: if the HTML is *not empty*, then `alert("empty")`.

You should change it to:

```
if (!$('.Itm_right_aside .toppcrustdata').html()) {
    alert('empty');
} else {
    alert('Not empty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if will be true if it has content then displays "empty" either change it to !$..... in the if or swap "empty" with "not Empty"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
if ($('.toppcrustdata').html() == '') {
    alert('empty');
} else {
    alert('Not empty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if is something inside then show "empty".

It should be:

```
if ($('.Itm_right_aside .toppcrustdata').html().length == 0) {
    alert('empty');
} else {
    alert('Not empty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `.toppcrustdata` div is a parent element, then you can test like this as well:

```
if ($('.Itm_right_aside .toppcrustdata').children().length == 0) {

    alert('empty');
} else {
    alert('Not empty');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/tdzfhzjy/79/)